# How to use a wild card for BrowserRouter and a Phoenix project

Tags: reactjs, graphql, phoenix-framework

I was hoping to get some help on understand how to use `BrowserRouter` with Phoenix. When I first created the project, I decided not to use any html (controllers/views) and fully depend on GraphQL/React. Resulting in my routes to be

```
  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end


  scope "/" do
    pipe_through :api

    forward "/api", Absinthe.Plug,
      schema: HuntersWeb.Schema.Schema

    forward "/graphiql", Absinthe.Plug.GraphiQL,
      schema: HuntersWeb.Schema.Schema,
      socket: HuntersWeb.UserSocket
  end
```

The problem I'm getting is when I use `BrowserRouter` and for example try to access `/signup`, instead of the component being run I get a `Cannot Get /signup`. I was hoping to get some advice on how to use a wild card to solve this problem? Would I need to create a controller/view in order for it to work?

All help, advice and pointing in the right direction to better understand this approach and solution to the problem is appreciated :) If more information is needed please ask as well.

**React Code**

```
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
```

**UPDATE**

Client.js

```
const HTTP_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4000/api";

const WS_ENDPOINT = "ws://localhost:4000/socket";

// Create an HTTP link to the Phoenix app's HTTP endpoint URL.
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: HTTP_ENDPOINT
});
```

Config.exs

```
config :cors_plug,
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
  max_age: 86400,
  methods: ["GET", "POST"]
```

Comment: How do you serve your react code to the browser? Is it via phoenix or via a separate project?

Comment: @JonasDellinger Thank you for replying. It's through a separate project. Was trying to keep Phoenix in a backend directory and React within a frontend directory.

Comment: And how do you access each service? Normally, phoenix runs on port `:4000` and a webpack dev server on `:8080`, do you already have something like a reverse proxy in front of it?

Comment: @JonasDellinger I'm running Phoenix on port `:4000` and getting it listen to a put/get request from a port `:3000` which is the frontend. I'm placing the code for backend and frontend for this one.

Comment: I guess your react dev-server is the problem then. Normally it handles all requests and Redirects them to index.html. Maybe have a look at the `historyApiFallback: true` setting of the Dev server?

Comment: @JonasDellinger Thank you. That did solve the problem for dev environment but I'm also trying to figure out how this will be solved when pushed to production. But thank you for the help and advice on this one :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201179/discussion-between-jonas-dellinger-and-steven-ossorio).